# Getting a seg fault in C++ doubly linked list insert function

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am writing a doubly linked list for my C++ class, and am having trouble with an insert function.  The idea is to insert a value into a sorted list in the correct spot (i.e., after a lower number, before a higher number).  The function works in that it inserts numbers in the correct spots, but I get a seg fault when I try to assign the pointers to take into account the new node.  The specific line is:

```
nodePtr->previous = newNode;
```

I use the same syntax to assign the pointers from nodePtr in other spots with no problem, so I can't understand why the seg fault here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: It seems to have been a problem with attempting to access the previous pointer after nodePtr had been set to nullptr.  An if statement check before hand handled to case.

from the .h:

```
struct ListNode {
    double value;
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *previous;
};

ListNode *head;
```

from the .cpp:

```
void NumberList::insertNode(double num)
{
ListNode *newNode;
ListNode *nodePtr;
ListNode *previousNode;
newNode = new ListNode;
newNode->value = num;

if(!head)
{
    head = newNode;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
}
else
{
    nodePtr = head;
    previousNode = nullptr;
    while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->value < num)
    {
        previousNode = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        if (nodePtr != nullptr)
            nodePtr->previous = previousNode;
    }
    if (previousNode == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = nodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr->previous = newNode;/*This is the line that seg faults.*/
        previousNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = nodePtr;
        newNode->previous = previousNode; 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nowhere do I see you initializing any pointers: they do not start at NULL by default, nor do they point to usable objects by default.

Comment: I have tried initializing nodePtr->previous to nullptr, but the seg fault still occurred, so I removed it.

Comment: hat about the other pointers? `head`, `next`, `previous`, and `nodePtr` ? All of them should be initialized to nullptr. Step through the code with a debugger, and see which things are being used before they're ever given a proper value.

Comment: I guess you need to change the check `if (previousNode == nullptr)` to `if (nodePtr == nullptr)`

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you will be inserting at the end of the list `nodePtr` will become `null`, then line

```
nodePtr->previous = newNode; // seg fault
```

will result in SEG fault. You have to handle that case.

Check if `nodePtr` is `null` or not before accessing it...

```
if(nodePtr)
    nodePtr->previous = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your head's pointer to point to nullptr before performing any of these operations. Otherwise, you are trying to dereference a pointer to a bad memory address, which results in a segmentation fault.

When you initialize head, try
`ListNode *head = nullptr;`

Comment: `head` is already initialized to `newNode` !! that's not a problem

Comment: Looks like `head` has static storage duration, though. It'll be zero initialized when the program starts.

Comment: `if(!head)
{
    head = newNode;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
} `  here that case is handled

Comment: This is my fault for not including in the interest of brevity, the constructor initializes head to nullptr.  The if statement Rajeev mentions is for the case where the list hasn't been created yet.